# check if hashmap contains value other than certain value

Tags: java, search, hashmap

I am trying to implement `HashMap` in JAVA, in my algorithm, i have to find if any of the keys contain values other than a specific value....for instance, lets say, all the keys in the map should have value 0 stored in them.

How can i check if, the map contains value which is not equal to 0.

I tried this but logically it isn't correct i know :

```
if(!hm.containsValue(0)) /* where hm is hashmap object*/
```

Comment: "searching a value in hashmap is done in constant time O(1)" --> uhm no, that would be for key lookup, and even then it's not O(1)

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question. Are you implementing your own `HashMap`, or using the one provided by Java? BTW, searching for value in a `HashMap` is not an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @fge : deleted that last line...your comment added to my knowledge :)

Comment: @RohitJain : m implement JAVA's default,basically trying to find anagram words...but it fails for `field` and `fieldd` because i dont have proper checks for values stored in map,so was wondering to check the hashmap values in one go....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate over all the values and check each one to see if it's not equal to zero, and that's `O(n)`. There's no alternative using a `Map`, a `Map` is efficient for finding *keys*, not for finding something in the *values*. For example, using the standard `Map` implementation in Java:

```
Integer zero = new Integer(0);
for (Integer i : hm.values()) {
    if (!zero.equals(i)) {
        System.out.println("found one non-zero value");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could theoretically throw an NPE, but... ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez : noob question, what is the purpose of this line `Integer zero = new Integer(0);` i mean i understand defining an integer, but `(0)` in it does what???

Comment: @NoobEditor `new Integer(0)` it's a call to `Integer` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(int)). When you write `0` you're not creating an `Integer`, but an `int`. This would also work and is equivalent: `Integer zero = 0;` but because under the hood [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is happening.

Answer (score 2):

you can define the map as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

And check if it contains a non-zero value as follows :

```
    for ( Integer value: map.values()) {
        if ( value != 0) {
            // non-zero value found in the map
        }
    }
```

Comment: updated the answer to check if it contains certain value

Comment: you can change the definition to :                           Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Comment: your solution gives answer for `does map continues this value`...my question is for `does map continues value other than this value` ....

Comment: so, you want to check if the map values contain other than zero?

Comment: ok...understand it this way....after all operations,my map is going to have values like `0,0,-1,1,0,0` .....but ideally it should have only `0,0,0,0,0,0`....so i need to check if the map contains values other than `0` too!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47560/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-manoj-shrestha)

Comment: i'll give a +1, but is almost same as the accepted answer...still,thankx for ur time mate!! :)